# Is it possible to compare two columns in excel and update the master column using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have two sheets in my excel workbook.
Contained in these sheets are my primary key columns.
I want to compare the first column (which is the master) to the second column (source) using a VBA loop.
The reason is because the source usually contains new primary keys.
Please can anyone be kind enough to help me figure out a logic to compare these columns and add the unique values to the master column. 
Thank you.

[this image shows the sample  master code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFKkk.png)
 [this image shows the sample source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41gRc.png)

The code below shows what I have so far

```
Sub PullUniques()
Dim rngCell As Range
For Each rngCell In Sheet1.Range("W3:W40")
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D3:D40"), rngCell) = 0 Then
        Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rngCell
    End If
Next
For Each rngCell In Sheet6.Range("D3:D40")
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("W3:W40"), rngCell) = 0 Then
        Range("W" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rngCell
    End If
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: We can better answer your question if you can supply a sample of your data and show us the VBA code you've tried so far.

Comment: Should we understand that you need to add in the master sheet (col A:A) the values which exist only in the source sheet (col A:A), but they cannot be found in master?

Comment: Yes @FaneDuru that is exactly what i want

Comment: I will prepare an answer. But if you will not make some research and edit your question  posting a piece of code, your question can be closed until I will post that...

Comment: ok thanks. I am editing it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, please. It is based on the assumption that in source sheet there could be keys not existing in your "Master" sheet, which will be add on the first empty row of the master sheet.

```
Sub testMasterUpdate()
  Dim shM As Worksheet, shS As Worksheet, s As Long, boolF As Boolean
  Dim lastRM As Long, lastRS As Long, m As Long
  Dim arrM As Variant, arrS As Variant, arrDif As Variant, d As Long

  Set shM = Worksheets("Master") 'please, use here your sheet name
  Set shS = Worksheets("Source") 'please, use here your sheet name
   lastRM = shM.Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   lastRS = shS.Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   arrM = shM.Range("A2:A" & lastRM).value
   arrS = shS.Range("A2:A" & lastRS).value
   ReDim arrDif(1 To 1, 1 To UBound(arrM) + UBound(arrS)): d = 1

   For s = 1 To UBound(arrS)
        For m = 1 To UBound(arrM)
            If arrS(s, 1) = arrM(m, 1) Then
                boolF = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next m
        If Not boolF Then
            arrDif(1, d) = arrS(s, 1)
            d = d + 1
        End If
        boolF = False
   Next s
   If d > 1 Then
     ReDim Preserve arrDif(1 To 1, 1 To d - 1)
     'shM.Range("A" & lastRM + 1).Resize(UBound(arrDif, 2), 1).value = _
                                    WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrDif)
     shM.Range("A" & lastRM).Resize(UBound(arrDif, 2), 1).value = _
                                WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrDif)
     lastRM = shM.Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     shM.Range("A" & lastRM + 1).Formula = "=CountA(A2:A" & lastRM & ")"
   End If
End Sub
```

Please, replace generic sheet names with your real ones.

Comment: @Philip Ajino: Bow I will leave my office. If you need clarifications, I will be able to answer after about two hours...

Comment: First of all, I want to thank you for you help. When i run the code and change the values, it gives a run-time error :"Subscript out of range" and when i debug it, it highlights the line with "arrDif(1, d) = arrS(s, 1)". What do you think might be causing this error.

Comment: You should initialize `arrDif` to the size of `arrS` rather than  `arrM`.  This is probably the cause of the OPs error

Comment: It will be better, but I do not think this is the problem. It looks improbanle the arrDiff size to not be enough for differences...

Comment: QPhilip Ajino: I prepared the code starting from the next assumption: You have a master sheet keeping all "primary keys" and another one where people input new keys. Besides the new ones there also are old codes. But, it kooks the situation may be different... I will adapt the code to work independent of the above assumption. Solved. Can you check it now, please?

Comment: I don't know how to thank you enough. I am really grateful for your help and assistance. Also @chrisneilsen , Your suggestion also worked. Thank you both. I hope to one day reach that level of sophistication in helping people solve important problems.

Comment: One more thing. Assuming i want to insert these primary keys between rows, how might i go about it. Thanks

Comment: Plese better define "between rows"... I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: okay. Assuming the rows from A1 to A16 have columns that contain data, and row A17 has formulas for summing the entire column, I want to be able to add this primary just before row A17 . So if there are 10 additions, the cell with the formula is moved to cell A27. Do you get now?. I know how to insert the rows using  `Range("A" & i + 2).EntireRow.Insert` but i don't know how i will add those primary keys

Comment: QPhilip Ajino: Do you count your keys on the last row? Do you mean to insert the new found keys on the row above the last one? If yes, it is possible, but it will complicate a little the code. The best way would be to drop the array content on the row above the last and write (in code) your formula on the last empty cell. If this is what you want, please write (here) your existing formula. I will adapt the code after 6 to seven hours, when I will be at home. If not, please describe your need even better... :)

Comment: QPhilip Ajino: In fact, I updated the code in order to do what I explained above. I used a simple `CountA` formula. If you have a different one, you can adapt it accordingly. But take care to use double quotes ("") instead of single ones("), if the case. And try understanding the way of calculated last row use...

Comment: Let me not burden you with the formulas. Majority of the formulas are to sum the columns eg (SUM A1:AEND). So if you can do just one  i can add as many as I want. Thanks

Comment: Do you have more formulas in A:A column cells? If yes, do all matter for rhe code? Wouldn't it be enough to rewrite the last one and rebuild it after the new keys have been added? Did you test the updated code. Please refresh the page in order to see it...

Comment: I just tried it now and it working. Thank you so much @FraneDuru. You''re the best